# Subview behind parent view within a ViewController?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, subview

Is it possible to display a sub-view behind the parent view? Obviously you could do this if the views were siblings; my views however are part of a ViewController hierarchy, and as far as I can tell, a ViewController can't have multiple views.

In other words, I have this hierarchy:

```
ViewController
-->ViewController's view
------>subview
```

Basically, I just want "subview" to be behind "ViewController's view."  None of this is modal -- both views are present the whole time.

Context: "ViewController's view" is the main view of an OGL-based application.  I need to display a constant background (user-selectable) behind the main view.

Comment: Subviews are usually added to the top of the view stack, however, the question is a bit confusing, you ask how to add a subview on top of your viewcontroller's view, but then you say you want to add a background behind the main view....So what are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: Subviews *are* "on top" of their parent view. Also, you are perfectly welcome to add layers to your view hierarchy if it makes sense to do so. There is no rule that the VC's "main" view needs to do any drawing. It can simply be a container for your two sibling views if you actually need 2 siblings to the the "main" view.

Comment: Ooops!  I wrote that question backward!  I want the sub-view *behind* the parent view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Justin is right, your question is confusing as placing a view (1) on top of another view (2) will obscure the original view (1). I think you meant to ask if you can add a subview "behind" or "below" the viewController's "main" view. The answer is no you can only add subviews onto the "main" view (the viewcontroller's view property).

However, just add the background view to the main view (the viewcontroller's view property) and then add your other views on top.

Btw, viewController's are meant to control multiple views (the main view and it's children).

Comment: Can a viewController treat multiple views as siblings?

Comment: If you had a main view that had two children, the two children would be siblings of each other. You could also have a main view that has two children that are siblings of each other and each of those children could have multiple children that would be siblings of each other etc. I think you want a main view that has a background view as a subview and that this is the parent of other views that are siblings of each other). Btw, as you add subviews they are placed on top, you can bring a subview to the front using bringSubviewToFront.

Comment: Right, that would work. I would create an empty view and connect it as the direct descendant of the viewController; attach the main view to the empty view; and attach the background view to the empty view.  Then, the main and background views would be siblings, and could be re-ordered.  My concern, though, is that there is a "special" relationship between the viewController and its direct descendant, and moving my main view a level further down the hierarchy might break something.  Should I be concerned about that?

Comment: Let me expand on that concern:  the viewController is a GLKViewController, and the main view is a GLKView.

Comment: If it were me, the only concern I would have would be in case of orientation changes and making sure I repositioned everything correctly when necessary but shouldn't be an issue if you don't nest multiple viewcontrollers.

Comment: Btw, (if it fits your requirements) instead of your main view and the background view being siblings, you could make the main view a child of the background view and make the background view the view controller's "top" view property view. The problem you might hit there though is changing the background view's child image view (if you need to change it that is).

Comment: Ok, I tried the empty view->main - background idea I described above.  Worked fine.  Moving the GLKView down a level didn't seem to affect it. Haven't tried changing orientations yet, but thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 0):

Create your background view, probably a UIImageView or something, then add it as a subview and move it to the back.

```
UIImageView *backgroundImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage.png"]];
[backgroundImage setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
[self.view addSubview:backgroundImage];
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:backgroundImage];
```

You can use `sendSubviewToBack:`, `bringSubviewToFront:`, `insertSubview:aboveSubview:`, `insertSubview:belowSubview:`, `insertSubview:atIndex:`, `exchangeSubviewAtIndex:withSubviewAtIndex:` to organize the hierarchy of the subviews (who is on top of who.)  The `subviews` property returns an `NSArray` of all of the subviews in order that they appear on the screen.

Comment: That only works with sibling views.  My background is a sub-view of the viewController's view.  I thought of that, too, but when I tried it, the sub-view remained on top of the viewController view.

Comment: In the example I wrote above, I am adding the subview to the view controller's view.  How are you adding the subview exactly??

Comment: To expand.  A viewController has a `view` and each `view` has an `NSArray` of `subviews` that are contained within that view.  Then, on top of that, each of those `subviews` can have their own `subviews`, etc.  This sibling stuff needs to be placed in those terms to make more sense.  If you are adding this as a subview, what view are you adding it as a subview to?  Are you adding it to the viewcontroller's view?  Or are you adding it to a subview of the viewcontroller's view?